# Can different styles be read by Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, code-documentation

Can Both Style of comments below be read by Doyxgen?

The Doxy Block Comments are in this format:

```
/**
* \brief
* \param
* \return
*/
```

and the ones in the libstdc++ are in this format:

```
/**
* @brief
* @param
* @return
*/
```

Comment: What did you try to do so far to check if it is possible or not? (it is).

Comment: @albert 
 
I haven't tried anything yet. I am still trying to figure out how to use doxygen with codeblocks. I already installed doxygen though and I read through the directions in man but they made absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @albert all of the above work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to test both methods in the original question and they both work. Also the additional method posted in one of the answers works as well. If you have other methods that work please add them. Thank you everybody for the advice.

Oh and by the way if you are using codeblocks. The software does not come with doxygen pre-installed. You have to install it to use the doxyblocks features.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct formats are like:

```
/*!
  \brief
  \param
  \return
*/
```

and

```
/**
 * @brief
 * @param
 * @return
 */
```

Mixed style couldn't work.

Comment: The place I got the doxyblocks style is from codeblocks. But Ill try them all and figure out what works and doesn't Ill try and test it sometime in the next week.